# How to change position on next trade based on last open order?

Tags: pine-script

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. I am using pyramiding and need each new order to be 10% of the previous one. My code keeps getting an invalid qty error.

```
lastEntryPrice = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
lastEntrySize = strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades - 1)

_qty = input.float(.03, "1st entry qty %", step=0.01)
qty1 = (strategy.equity * _qty) / close
qty2 = lastEntrySize*0.1


if long and strategy.opentrades == 0
    strategy.cancel_all()
    strategy.order("Long", strategy.long, qty=qty1, limit=close)
    strategy.exit("E_L1", "Long", profit = profit)

if long and close < lastEntryPrice
    strategy.cancel_all()
    strategy.order("Long", strategy.long, qty=qty2, limit=close)
```

Comment: Check if `lastEntrySize` has finite value (not na). make sure that you round your contract size to the min qty value of the symbol (e.g. 1 for the stocks, 0.001 for the most of crypto).